# How to enable pdo_mysql in the php docker image

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I have a basic `Dockerfile` with the following in:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
RUN apt-get update && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
COPY . /var/www
EXPOSE 80
```

I have a docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "app"
      MYSQL_USER: "app"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "app"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "test"
```

I then ran `docker build -t app . && docker-compose up` at the root of the project. Everything seems to build correctly, but when outputting `phpinfo` I don't see the mysql_pdo extension.

[image]

Are there any steps I am missing?

Comment: did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 52):

The docker file I use is...

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
```

Note the mysqli and pdo  in there as well to allow the PDO/mysql bit.

Comment: I still get the same issue with the extra modules included

Comment: @Tom have you removed the container and started from scratch, this is only built on the first startup of the container.

Comment: Yeah I think so. I stopped the active containers then ran `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

Comment: Sorry - the config is based on the image it builds from the base image.  So use `docker images` to find the image for php (mine created 'docker_php') and then use `docker rmi IMAGEID` (replacing it with the one in your listing).  Then restart docker and this should rebuild the image with the new options.

Comment: @NigelRen I tried it with `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)` command and yet, still have the problem described above. What's interesting is the fact that `mysql` works, `pdo_mysql` not.

Answer (score 21):

to enabled PHP PDO and mysqli extensions to connect with MySQL
add in Dockerfile :

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
# for mysqli if you want
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

More Information to how to create that visit this [Page](https://github.com/Al-Alloush/Docker-mysql-and-PHP-pdo-mysqli-extension)

Comment: **Confirmed Working** To further add to @Ahmad Al ALloush answer, [php - Official Image | Docker - How to install more PHP extensions](https://hub.docker.com/_/php). PHP extensions need to be both installed and enabled via the `docker-php-ext-install` and `docker-php-ext-enable` functions.

Answer (score 7):

There was a [similar error in docker php issue 62](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/62#issuecomment-300068795):

> As it turn out that I need to remove the old images and rebuild them again.
>
> Cause I downloaded the image, then edit it. So I need to remove the old image and rebuild it in order to apply the change.

docker rm only removes containers. Make sure you remove your image as well before.

Also check if a [Dockerfile like this one](https://github.com/AminMkh/docker-php7-apache/blob/master/Dockerfile) might be more robust/complete:

```
# PHP extensions
RUN \
    docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure mysqli --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    ...
```

Comment: This one works @VonC with refernce to the documention at [https://hub.docker.com/_/php](https://hub.docker.com/_/php)

Answer (score -1):

I am using this and works fine for me.

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y git zlib1g-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip
```

If its not working for your. Please attache docker build output for review.